# Unable to understand a pointer statement

Tags: c, pointers, puts

I am doing a ctf problem and there is a line i can't understand.

```
int  (*fp)(char *)=(int(*)(char *))&puts, i;
```

Can anyone explain me what does this mean?

Comment: Use link: [fp as pointer to function (pointer to char) returning int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int++%28*fp%29%28char+*%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fp` is a pointer

```
(*fp)
```

to a function

```
(*fp)(
```

that accepts 1 argument of type `char`

```
(*fp)(char)
```

and returns a value of type `int`

```
int (*fp)(char)
```

The pointer is initialized with the address of `puts` after a mostly redundant conversion.

```
int  (*fp)(char *)=(int(*)(char *))&puts
int  (*fp)(char *)=(int(*)(char *))puts // & redundant
int  (*fp)(const char *)=puts
```

The object `i` is not initialized. It has type `int`

```
int  (*fp)(char *)=(int(*)(char *))&puts, i;
```

Answer (score 2):

First there is a variable declaration:

```
int  (*fp)(char *)
```

`fp` is a pointer to function, which is taking a `char *` parameter and returning `int`.

Then `fp` is initialized to a value:

```
(int(*)(char *))&puts
```

The value is the address of the `puts` function, cast to the same type as `fp`.

And finally, there is another variable declaration:

```
int /* ... */, i;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this declaration:

```
int  (*fp)(char *)=(int(*)(char *))&puts, i;
```

**first** is: int  `(*fp)(char *)=(int(*)(char *))&puts;`
explanation: This is function pointer declaration and initialisation in single statement. Where `fp` is the pointer to the function `puts`. If you print value of `fp` and `puts` they will have same value, that is address of `puts`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int  (*fp)(char *)=(int(*)(char *))&puts, i;
  printf("puts %p\n",puts);
  printf("fp %p\n",fp);
}
```

and **second** is: `int i;`